# Intellectual property rights for files uploaded to Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one, legal

I am an artist thinking about using Ubuntu One to back up my art / photos / other work.  I have a very important question about the files and photos that I upload to Ubuntu one:

Do I lose any rights of ownership by uploading the images and files to Ubuntu One?

I want to make sure that the files and images that I upload are still my property, and that Ubuntu has no right to use or sell them for any reason.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth I have read the TOS and the privacy part of Ubuntu One and it *seems* very straightforward. No funky stuff like in Dropbox's TOS. Dropbox clearly states that they have the right to sell and use your stuff whatever they like. I'm also pretty sure this is not something Canonical would like to do (and nor does it seem like they are wanting to) =)

However, if you are really worried; contact Ubuntu one and your lawyer to be sure.

I for one trust Canonical (and more so after I read the TOS)

For reading pleasure:
https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/
https://one.ubuntu.com/privacy/

Answer (score 1):

The TOS of Ubuntu One appears to only mention the copyright status of the client software, and of their server software.  Nowhere in the TOS or privacy policy it is mentioned that you are altering the copyright status of your data by uploading it to Ubuntu One.  They will share your data if served with a proper legal order to do so.

That said, this is a ***serious legal question***, and the answer would also depend on prevailing law.  Whatever anyone says, the only way to be absolutely sure is to ask ***your*** lawyer.

https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/#intellectual-property

Answer (score 0):

You can review the Terms & Conditions regarding intellectual property here:
https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/#intellectual-property

Comment: Is it about intellectual property of server software, or about intellectual property of the uploader ?